# Retrieving selective sheet data from "large Excel 2003" file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there any way to get a list of rows and cell values from an excel file. I have about 100,000 rows with 20 columns each. And the file is of '.xls' format. I have tried some ways like the [XLS2CSVmra](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-examples/3.6/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java) example. I am able to print everything in my excel file, but i need a way to get list of rows and columns,if possible sheet by sheet

**Note:** I know how to read and write. But for larger files it throws java heap error. and i figured out how to overcome that and get a list of rows for .xlsx files. i am not able to figure out for .xls files.

**Note 2** I followed the advice given in [HSSF event api](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api), and i'm able to get the data, but not in a list format. suppose i have 3 sheets with around 100,000 rows each, and i want only the list of rows in the second sheet, i'm not able to figure out a way to do that. by following the HSSF event api method im able to print the entire data, but not selectively. I'm still trying to figure out some way to achieve it. I'll post anything if i find a way. And please let me know if there is a way to do this. If not apache poi, then any other api.

Comment: I know how to read and write. But for larger files it throws java heap error. and i figured out how to overcome that for .xlsx files. i am not able to figure out for .xls files

Comment: are you already using apache-poi event model? https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api

Comment: yes i am. I followed the advice given there, and i'm able to get the data, but not in a list format. suppose i have 3 sheets with around 100,000 rows each, and i want only the list of rows in the second sheet, i'm not able to figure out a way to do that. by following the HSSF event api method im able to print the entire data, but not selectively. I'm still trying to figure out some way to achieve it. I'll post anything if i find a way. And please let me know if there is a way to do this. If not apache poi, then any other api.